# state_activated and ListView item background color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I'm trying to color an item's (when selected) background. I'm working with the Android emulator. I have a set of XML files in `res/drawable`.

background.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

normal.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

pressed.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#33ffff" />
</shape>
```

And my list_item.xml, with...my item :
`<TextView ... android:background="@drawable/background" android:padding="6dp" />`

Well, in the emulator `state_pressed="true"` works, however I want that the selected item remains colored. So, instead of `state_pressed` I tried `state_activated` ...but hey...doesn't works too. My item remains black...

Need some help :) !

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls refer to the link below:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html

try using state_focused for your case.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing happens I already tried with state_focused. Background is still black after a click on an item.

Comment: You want the background color on select or on click..The above will work fine for select.

Comment: I want to change the background color on click/touch. And once my item is clicked/touched/whatever I want to switch the background color of this item.

Comment: Then you can always override onItemSelected method and onItemClicked method and set the setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.test);

Comment: Yes indeed, but I'll have to keep a track of old colored item to reset to the original background color. I thought I could avoid that. :(

Answer (score 5):

I  believe state_activated is what you are looking for.

In your listselector.xml :

```
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/whatever" />
<item android:state_activated="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transaprent" />
```

Then in your code, implement an onItemClickListener and set your view to activated:

```
view.setActivated(true);
```

Hope this helps.

Tom