# Android ListView Item Background Color

Tags: android, listview, background-color

I am trying to allow the user to select more than one item. I want to "highlight" each list item selected so you can tell which item(s) have been selected.

I have tried:
`view.setBackgroundResource();
view.setBackgroundColor();
view.setBackgroundDrawable();`

I havent had any success.

Thannks for the help!

Comment: you can see this example to solve your problem. http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055277/set-a-background-color-to-a-selected-listview-item-in-android you may also see this links. [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector), [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217753/changing-background-color-of-listview-items-on-android) and [Link3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422438/state-activated-and-listview-item-background-color)

Comment: Try making ListAdapter class by extending the BaseAdapter and in getView() method you can write code for the selected item it could be onClickLitner of the listItem and there change the background color of the list.

Comment: why do people put answers in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom array adapter , if you are using a listview with only one element you MAY be able to get away with some implemented listview method, but you will have much more flexibility and less headache if you make a custom array adapter instead. You can access all elements in it, each element can have its own onClickListener and everything

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing a String array to the adapter,you can create custom adapter like this and can change background color of a selected item as below:

set the adapter to listview like:

```
String[] options={"abc","def","ghi","jkl"};

CustomAdapter ca=new CustomAdapter(this,options);    
listView.setAdapter(ca);
```

and here is the custom adapter class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        String items[];
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context,String[] items)
    {
        this.items=items;
        this.context=context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null)
        {
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cutsom_listitem, null);
             holder = new ViewHolder();

             holder.itemName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);

             convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();


        String option=items[position];
        holder.itemName.setText(option);

        holder.itemName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.itemName.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));  // making selected item red colored
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView itemName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can overwrite setOnTouchListener in your adapter:

view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

```
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch(event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                //the bacground when u select item
                v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                //设置背景为未选中正常状态
            v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.background_light);
                break;

            default:
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mm_listitem_simple);
                break;

            }
            return false;
        }
```

you can set diffrence background when your action hanppend.